# Repeater ItemTemplate Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing a problem with access to HTML elements.  On the server side those elements exists in `itemTemplate` of a repeater control.

simple code:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server" onitemcreated="rptList_ItemCreated">
    <HeaderTemplate>
               <div id="accordionGiftLelo">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>


                         <div class="set">
                         <div class="title"><img src='<%# Eval("TitleImgUrl")%>'  runat="server" width="198" height="29"  /></div>
                         <div ID="RepeaterBG" class="content"  style="background-color:<%# Eval("ContentBackground")%>">
                             <%--<a href='<%# Eval("ContentUrl")%>'><img src='<%# Eval("ContentImgUrl")%>' alt="Embroidered Devil Eyes" width="198" height="198" border="0" /></a>--%>
                             <div style="width:198"><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("ContentImgUrl")%>'></asp:Literal></div>
                         </div>
                         </div>

    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
                         </div>
    </FooterTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
```

How can I access `RepeaterBG` div for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to access controls server side and apply your data to them.  Make sure to add the RunAt="server" to the div tag.

add a reference for the ItemDataBound event

```
rptList.ItemDataBound += rptList_ItemDataBound;

private void rptList_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{   
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

    HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl RepeaterBG = (HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("RepeaterBG");

    Data.DataRowView dr = (Data.DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

    RepeaterBG.Style.Add("background-color", dr("ContentBackground"))
}
```

You will find that if you do this for ALL of your controls, instead of using "<%# Eval", you're code will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: thanks Carter for your help.

i hate VB and i didn't understand it so i use c#..

thanks any way..

Answer (score 0):

Use OnItemDataBound event of the repeater. You also need to add the runat="server" attribute to the RepeaterBG div.

```
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

    protected void rptList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            var div = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("RepeaterBG");

        }
    }
```

Comment: delete the style="background-color:<%# Eval("ContentBackground")%>" part, binding this way on server controls doesn't always work

Comment: but i have to do this... is there another way maybe adding this by server side could save the problem

Answer (score 0):

Its the quotes around your style tag:

```
<div ID="RepeaterBG" class="content"  style='background-color:<%# Eval("ContentBackground")%>'>
```

Comment: thank you rick schott for helping... i solve my problem as carter describe  thanks any way..